# How to differentiate between empty string and null with OpenCSV

Tags: java, null, opencsv

This is my code:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isReader);
while ((col = reader.readNext()) != null) {
   String c1 = col[1];
}
```

this is my csv file:

```
"a","","c"
"1",,"3"
```

Is there a way I can differentiate between null and ""? OpenCSV seems to treat everything as non-null String. Can I tell it to treat empty fields as null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: strictQuotes can be used to get nulls:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isReader, ',', '"', true);
while ((col = reader.readNext()) != null) {
   String c1 = col[1];
   if (null != c1) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Adding to @Gavriel's answer, starting from OpenCSV 3.6 (maybe earlier), I found that strictQuotes doesn't help with returning null anymore.

CSVReaderBuilder has withFieldAsNull() for this purpose.

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(csvFileReader)
    .withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.EMPTY_SEPARATORS)
    .build();
```

Comment: I believe this must be the correct answer, since most of the reader constructors are Deprecated. By the way the indicator has BOTH option as well which considers both empty seperators and empty quotes as null.

Comment: works for me only when set "withFieldAsNull" on CSVParserBuilder , not on CSVReaderBuilder , first create CSVParserBuilder  , and with it create CSVReaderBuilder like this - CSVReaderBuilder(new CSVParserBuilder(...)) - (open csv 5.0)

Comment: is there a way to do it by column?

Answer (score 6):

with open csv 5.0

```
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder()
                        .withSeparator(",")
                        .withQuoteChar('"')
                        .withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.BOTH)
                        .build();

                csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new InputStreamReader(...))
                        .withCSVParser(csvParser)
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible. There is no difference between an empty string and the java specific `null` in the `CSV` format's philosophy. The `null` is an empty reference in the `java` object memory model. In CSV there aren't any references, but only empty values.

Comment: There is. In the above csv example I would expect opencsv to notice the difference between ,, and ,"",. I would be OK with the default being convert everything to non-null String, but I would expect to have an optional parameter where I could override the default behavior and let opencsv know that whenever it sees a certain string it should consider it as NULL. But in order for this to work it has to be inside the parser (I can't extend opencsv to add this IMHO) because in the level I get to the data it's already converted to ""

Comment: @Gavriel, according to `CSV` format, `,,` and `,"",` are same things.

Comment: where is that standard? I thought there is no csv RFC yet

Comment: I don't see anything about empty fields there.