# Apache common CSVParser/CSVRecord to return null for empty fields

Tags: java, csv

I have a question for Apache common CSVParser/CSVRecord. Take a look at the CSV file below:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3
"",,"L1C3"
```

CSVParser/CSVRecord is returning "" for the first two columns. In my case I want to distinguish empty string("") and null values. Is there a configuration I could set to let CSVParser to return null for the second column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to differentiate between empty string and null with OpenCSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301620/how-to-differentiate-between-empty-string-and-null-with-opencsv)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a dupe, though I saw the other article as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is. You can see the exact same question.

Comment: Same question, different library, or not?

Comment: @TheProgrammerG although it's a different library. Don't think the one asked about can actually do this. And, of course, it's not obvious whether one really ought to do this.

Comment: One hack is to pre-process your file and replace your ""s with something else. Then you can use `withNullString` on `CVSFormat`

Comment: OpenCSV and Apache Common CSV are different libraries.

Answer (score 7):

I've used this format :

```
CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader()
   .withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces()
   .withNullString("")
```

Where the 2 configurations:

1. **ignore space** - which trims any value on both sides, if its all space, it will be trimmed to empty space
2. **null string** - which treats the empty spaces as null

Here's a sample usage:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CsvParseTest {

    @Test
    public void testParseWillTrimAndConvertToNull() throws Exception {
        String CSV_HEADER = "Name,MobileNo,Location";
        String CSV_ROW_1 = "abc,   ,australia"; // MobileNo is 3 whitespaces
        CSVParser parse = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces().withNullString("")
                .parse(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(CSV_HEADER + "\n" + CSV_ROW_1)));

        CsvRecord rec = parse.getRecords().get(0);
        assertEquals("abc", rec.get("Name"));
        assertNull(rec.get("MobileNo"));
        assertEquals("australia", rec.get("Location"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) is the only library that allows you to distinguish empty strings from nulls (*I know this won't address your problem with Apache Commons CSV directly, but at least there's a way to get what you need*).

Here's how to do it:

```
public static void main(String ... args){
    String input = "Header1,Header2,Header3\n" +
            "\"\",,\"L1C3\"";

    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial.
    settings.setEmptyValue("I'm empty"); //value to use when the parser finds "". Set to "" to get an empty String.
    settings.setNullValue("I'm null"); //value to use when the parser finds a null value (i.e. ,,). 

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new StringReader(input));

    for(String[] row : allRows){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
[Header1, Header2, Header3]
[I'm empty, I'm null, L1C3]
```

uniVocity-parsers is also 3 times faster than Apache Commons CSV and has way more features.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Answer (score 1):

At the end I didn't find a good solution to return null with Apache Commons CSV library. I switched to OpenCSV 3.6 and here is the code I used, which I also posted on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301620/how-to-differentiate-between-empty-string-and-null-with-opencsv/34736360#34736360). Thanks to everyone else that suggested OpenCSV.

CSVReaderBuilder has withFieldAsNull() for this purpose.

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(csvFileReader)
    .withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.EMPTY_SEPARATORS)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Apache commons csv 1.2, we could use the `CSVFormat` class method `withNullString()` to convert null strings to `NULL`. Here null string could be `""` or `"N/A"` or `"Nill"` according to your requirement.

```
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withNullString("");
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFormat);
```

This would give `NULL, NULL, L1C3` for the given record in question.

Note: Empty records are automatically converted to empty strings thus resulting in converted to `NULL` value at last.