# Using OpenCSV's CsvToBean, how can I define values to be converted to null?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am using OpenCSV's `CsvToBean` to map rows to my POJOs, but I can't seem to find a way to define string values that should be converted to `null`.

Say, if I wanted *"null"*, *"Null"*, *"N/A"* or anything else to be mapped as `null`, how should I proceed?

I've seen `StringProcessors` in the docs, but these would need to be applied with annotations to each and every field of the classes, which sounds tedious.

I also saw the `.withFieldAsNull` on the `CsvToBeanBuilder`, but it only offers conversion to null for empty separators or empty strings (*""*).

Thank you very much !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301620/how-to-differentiate-between-empty-string-and-null-with-opencsv

Comment: @JCompetence this doesn't answer my question, as it is not about custom values, but simply string vs nothing. It also is not using CsvToBean.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You would need to "write your own mapping strategy", but I think that it is totally sufficient if you override the part where the field value is set.