# OpenCSV not converting empty string to null POJO field

Tags: java, spring, opencsv

Using OpenCSV 5.9

How should I be configuring my `CsvToBeanBuilder` to convert empty Strings to null on my POJO. For example, the I'd expect the following POJO to have a `null` value for "lastName" - instead the value is `""`. I thought setting `.withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.BOTH)` would work but I'm still seeing empty Strings as the value for `lastName` instead of `null`

### CSV example

```
"FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME"
"Bob",""
```

### POJO

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Person {

  @CsvBindByName(column = "FIRST_NAME")
  private String firstName;

  @CsvBindByName(column = "LAST_NAME")
  private String lastName;

}
```

### Parser

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
@Qualifier("CsvParser")
public class CsvParser implements FileParser {

  @Override
  public List<Person> parse(InputStream inputStream) {
    log.debug("Parsing InputStream as CSV");

    return new CsvToBeanBuilder<Person>(new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)))
        .withType(Person.class)
        .withSeparator(',')
        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
        .withIgnoreEmptyLine(true)
        .withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.BOTH)
        .build()
        .parse();
  }
}
```

### Pom dependency

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
      <version>5.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to differentiate between empty string and null with OpenCSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301620/how-to-differentiate-between-empty-string-and-null-with-opencsv)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just writing a custom converter and using the `@CsvCustomBindByName`.

### POJO

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Person {

  @CsvCustomBindByName(column = "FIRST_NAME", converter = NonEmptyStringConverter.class)
  private String firstName;

  @CsvCustomBindByName(column = "LAST_NAME", converter = NonEmptyStringConverter.class)
  private String lastName;
}
```

### Converter

```java
public class NonEmptyStringConverter extends AbstractBeanField {

  @Override
  protected String convert(String s)
      throws CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvConstraintViolationException {
    return StringUtils.isNotEmpty(s) ? s : null;
  }
```